# How to remove all characters standing before a specific character- Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I searched all around but couldn't find any solutions.

Having lot of lines contains special character of "\"

Ex:
Test\Example\Sample\example.aspx

Test1\Example1\Sample\example2.aspx

I want delete all of text before the "\ so the unnecessary text like "Test\Example\Sample\" will be gone, only the name such as filename being kept. How can I do it?

Comment: Please show your efford and provide a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hint: You want to get the text from the last (not included) backslash, where there's no more backslash afterwards.

Comment: @Chrᴉz The OP appears to _not_ want the last backslash.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ty, my fault. i edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to find this: `.*\\` and replace it with nothing

Comment: Make sure you enable regex mode in the search box! I would also say it would be more thorough to use `^` at the start of the regex so that you can use Replace All without having to worry about the position of the cursor in the file.

Comment: Simply superb:-)